# CSharp Filtering A List With A LINQ query Using Another List And Its Nested List

Tags: c#, list, linq, nested-lists

I am trying to use a LINQ query on a list of courses to filter each course according to the students in the class' student list with the size of the student's grades average.
The students' grades are a list of doubles.

This is a simplified structure of the classes I am using for the code:

```
class Course{
    private string CourseName;
    private List<Course> StudentsList = new List<Student>{};

//This is a nested class
    public class Student{
        private string StudentName;
        private List<double> StudentGrades;
   }
}
```

The simplified code(assume each list and nested list is already initialized):

```
//The function GetAverage() takes the average of the student, calculates, and returns it.
//The code is inside the course class in a method called Q1.
var Above60 = from course in CoursesList
              from student in course.StudentList
              where student.GetAverage() > 60
              select course;

foreach(course in CoursesList){
   Console.WriteLine($"{course.CourseName});
}
```

Actual result(below are just the courses' names):

```
C#
C#
C#
SQL
SQL
SQL
JAVA 
JAVA
JAVA
```

I do not want the console to display to me the courses' names three times(only one time) as is shown in the code above.

Is there a way I can fix this?

thank you very much,
Dor

Comment: you can use thi in loop `CoursesList.Distinct(p => p.CourseName)`...or `group p by new {p.CourseName}
                   into groupBy
                   select groupBy.FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: Do you mean private List< **Student** > StudentsList = new List<Student>{}; and not  private List< **Course** > StudentsList = new List<Student>{};?

Answer (score 0):

To filter out the courses with duplicate names from `CoursesList`, use the [`.Distinct`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=net-5.0) LINQ extension method.

This should produce expected output:

```
var uniqueCourseNames = CoursesList.Distinct(c => c.CourseName);

foreach(course in uniqueCourseNames){
   Console.WriteLine($"{course.CourseName});
}
```